# Hide or delete an entry in a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which is populated by a MySQL query

```
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($phresult)) 
{
    if ($ID == $myrow["Cmpy_ID"])
    {
        printf("
    <option value=\"%s\" selected>%s</option>\n", $myrow["Cmpy_ID"], $myrow["Provider_Name"]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("
    <option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", $myrow["Cmpy_ID"], $myrow["Provider_Name"]);
    }
}
```

This query is used several times in the application but only in this one certain case I'd like to exclude the entry where Provider_Name = 'Foo'.

I'd prefer not to change it or include an extra query just for this case, so is there a way to remove an entry from the dropdown after it has been populated?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman, which I could double up-vote! Back to topic: after you have populated the dropdown? No. You can exclude it for when populating it though by a simply guard, i.e. `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During PHP execution, you can skip when the value is `Foo`:

```
<?php
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($phresult)) 
{
    if($myrow["Provider_Name"]=='Foo')
            continue;

    if ($ID == $myrow["Cmpy_ID"])
    {
        printf("
    <option value=\"%s\" selected>%s</option>\n", $myrow["Cmpy_ID"], $myrow["Provider_Name"]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("
    <option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", $myrow["Cmpy_ID"], $myrow["Provider_Name"]);
    }
}
```

Or go by JQuery:

```
$("#selector option[value='Foo']").remove();
```

By the way mysql is deprecated, go for mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i meant to say is that the sample code is used many times in other places and I'd prefer not to alter it by adding the continue in this way. Is there some way of doing it removing it after it has been added?

Comment: That is why I added jQuery too. Add that in document ready function, and replace selector with your select element ID